# Persisting Money with Spring Data JDBC

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, mapping, spring-data-jdbc

Let's take a following entity:

```
class Item{
    @Id
    Long id;
    String name;
    org.joda.money.Money price;
}
```

and a corresponding repository:

```
interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, Long> {
}
```

Is it possible to persist Item in a relational DB table having amount and currency in separate columns without manually rewriting SQL queries offered by `ItemRepository`?

DDL could be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM (
    ID             INTEGER IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    NAME           VARCHAR(255)     NULL,
    PRICE_AMOUNT   DECIMAL          NULL,
    PRICE_CURRENCY VARCHAR(3)       NULL
);
```

Storing Money in a single `VARCHAR` column using custom `@WritingConverter` and `@ReadingConverter` is the closest I got, however this is not an option, as I need amount and currency clearly separated at the DB level.

I'm fine with replacing `joda.money` in favor of `javax.money` if that makes a difference, however I do not want to introduce my own custom type for handling money in domain layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the following options available to persist properties of non standard types in Spring Data JDBC

1. Use `@WritingConverter` and `@ReadingConverter` in order to convert the value to something Spring Data JDBC knows. You already discovered that this works only with single columns
2. You can mark it as an [`@Embedded`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#jdbc.entity-persistence.embedded-entities) which will convert each attribute to a column. I'm not sure if `Money` has suitable attributes but it is lacking a suitable constructor so this doesn't work either.
3. Use a different type that you can handle with one of the first approaches. In this case this would mean write your own `Money` type which has a suitable constructor and attributes to work as an embedded.
4. Tweak your database: you can create a view which uses a single column representation and stores it as a single column. It might still make it available as separate columns for sorting and filtering.